# Module specific routing using hmvc in code igniter?

Tags: codeigniter, routes, hmvc

I am using Code igniter with HMVC,

We are creating drop-in modules.

One thing I am a bit stuck on though is the routing.

I can add

```
$route['gallery/categories'] = 'gallery/categorieseditor';
$route['gallery/categories/(:any)] = 'gallery/categorieseditor/$1';
```

to the main routes.php config file and it works fine.

But I don't want to have to edit the main routes file for the modules.

I was hoping I could just drop this into a `routes.php` file  in `/modules/gallery/config/` But visiting the url just gives me a 404 (accessing `/gallery/categorieseditor` works).

How can I get this up and running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your code:

`$route['gallery/categories/(:any)] = 'gallery/categorieseditor/$1';`

Should be:

`$route['gallery/categories/(:any)'] = 'gallery/categorieseditor/$1';`